# How to set a button to most right side of navigation - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I set a button to right side of navigation bar:

my view controller:
[image]

I want to set a burger icon,red cycle and a label  to this button. like this:

[image]

my code:

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = self.utilities.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#00b8de")

    var imageview2 = UIImage(named: "menulogo")

    imageview2 = imageview2?.imageResize(sizeChange: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))

    btnMenu.setImage(imageview2,for:UIControlState.normal)
    btnMenu.setTitle("", for: .normal)


    // setup the red circle UIView
    let redCircleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    redCircleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    redCircleView.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.width / 2

    // setup the number UILabel
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
    label.text = "16"

    // adding the label into the red circle
    redCircleView.addSubview(label)

    // adding the red circle into the menu button
    btnMenu.addSubview(redCircleView)
```

with above codes I have three problems:

1. my burger image isn't in most right side of navigation.
2. my cycle view doesn't show
3. my icon is white, but it shows blue!

`btnMenu` is my button in navigation.

[image]

Comment: Well, I got a solution for your case, but I want to make sure that: is it ok if the button has been tapped without showing the highlighting effect (the effect that appears on the button when the user keeps pushing it)?

Comment: ok, I like to know your solution. after click on burger icon, right menu will appear.

Answer (score 0):

I have use this library for set badge on navigation button.

> MIBadgeButton is badge button written in Swift with high
>   UITableView/UICollectionView performance.

https://github.com/mustafaibrahim989/MIBadgeButton-Swift

Comment: In my opinion, there is no need to integrate with a library to doing such a thing, it is not that complicated to use one. Also, it might be has not suitable  constrains for the developer.

Comment: "to doing" meant: to do (or for doing). "complicated to use one" meant: complicated to implement one. I really need to sleep!